# Redirect to amazon page login and pass with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services

Please help me with this: I have a site with affiliates from amazon and when customer buy the item he will be redirected to amazon log in form, but what I want to add to that link (button) which will redirect to my amazon account and to add thru Javascript credentials(log in and password).
Here are a few screens to understand:

**First Screen**
[image: First Screen]

**Second Screen**
[image: Second Screen]

Comment: You want your customers to log in to your amazon account?

Comment: Yes Sure, I want this

Comment: This does not seem like a good idea.